# how to type parameters of a function as an object value based on the key

Tags: typescript, inferred-type

I am having difficulties in writing the type of `configArgs`  Can anybody help?

```
const path = {
  A: 'home',
  B: 'support',
  C: 'contact'
} as const
type B = unknown
const B: B = {};
const config = {
  [path.A]: () => null,
  [path.B]: (): B => B,

  [path.C]: ({
    active,
  }: {
    active: boolean
  }) => B,
} as const

type Config = typeof config

type ConfigArgs = {
  [P in keyof Config]: Config[P] extends (a: infer A) => any ? A : never // this is not working
}

function getConfig<T extends A>(
  path: A,
  args?: ConfigArgs[R]
): B | null {
  return config[path](args) 
}
```

I would expect to see the correct arguments type whenever i call the `getConfig` function with the path.

```
getConfig("pathA") // no type errors
getConfig("pathC", {active:true}) // no type errors
getConfig("pathC", {id:"xxx"}) // has type errors, as parameters are wrong
getConfig("pathC") // has type errors, as function needs params.
getConfig("pathA", {active:true}) // has type errors, cause the function does not expect any params
```

Comment: Please provide a self-contained [mre] that demonstrates your issue when pasted as-is into a standalone IDE.  Without definitions of `A`, `B`, and apparently `R`, I have lots of errors presumably unrelated to what you're asking about.

Comment: Unfortunately this is still not a [mre]; see [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/weBGEN); do you see all the errors? There's no definition for `A`, `B`, or `R`. Please [edit] with code that fixes those errors, or it's hard to help.

Comment: A, B is an abstraction. It is a type does not really matter in this context. @jcalz

Comment: Unfortunately my IDE doesn't understand abstractions, and while I might understand them, I am a poor TypeScript compiler.  In order to begin to work on this, I'd need to invent some definitions of `A`, `B`, and whatever `R` is, and then *hope* that they demonstrated the issue you're facing.  It would be better if you would do that instead, so that everyone would be on the same page. Anyway I won't bother you again about it.  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz a typescript playground link would help maybe? :) shorturl.at/cpIMS

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WylKgm) meet your needs?  If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?  Note that if it does work I will probably [edit] the code in your question to conform exactly to what's in your playground link, since any relevant code should be in plaintext in the question.

Comment: @jcalz awesome!! That was all i need!  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you need to support is strong typing for the *callers* of `getConfig()`, then you can make it [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type `K` of the `path` argument, and use [the `Parameters<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) and [the `ReturnType<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype) utility types to represent the input/output relationship:

```
declare function getConfig<K extends keyof Config>(
  path: K,
  ...args: Parameters<Config[K]>
): ReturnType<Config[K]>;
```

which works as expected:

```
getConfig(path.A) // okay
getConfig(path.B, { id: "xxx" }) // error, expected 1 arg but got 2
getConfig(path.C) // error // error, expected 2 args but got 1
getConfig(path.C, { active: true }) // okay
getConfig(path.C, { id: "xxx" }) // error, {id: string} is not {active: boolean}
```

---

However, you'll find that the compiler won't be able to verify that the *implementation* of this function is correct:

```
function getConfig<K extends keyof Config>(
  path: K,
  ...args: Parameters<Config[K]>
): ReturnType<Config[K]> {
  return config[path](...args); // error! 
  // ---------------> ~~~~~~~ A spread argument must have a tuple type
  // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <-- unknown is not assignable to type...
}
```

That's a current limitation of TypeScript; generic [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) like `Parameters<Config[K]>` and `ReturnType<Config[K]>` are essentially opaque to the compiler.  You can still use these types, but you'll need to use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) in the implementation to suppress errors, and take care that you've done the work correctly because the compiler can't help here:

```
function getConfig<K extends keyof Config>(
  path: K,
  ...args: Parameters<Config[K]>
) {
  return (config as any)[path](...args) as ReturnType<Config[K]>
  //             ^^^^^^ <-- assert ---> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

If you want the compiler to follow the generic logic, you will need to refactor to using [indexed accesses](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) on generic [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109):

```
type ConfigArgs = { [K in keyof Config]: Parameters<Config[K]> }
type ConfigRet = { [K in keyof Config]: ReturnType<Config[K]> }

const _config: { [K in keyof Config]:
  (...args: ConfigArgs[K]) => ConfigRet[K]
} = config;

function getConfig<K extends keyof Config>(
  path: K,
  ...args: ConfigArgs[K]
) {
  return _config[path](...args)  // okay, seen as ConfigRet[K]
}
```

Here we define both `ConfigArgs` and `ConfigRet` as a mapped type on `Config`, and then define the `_config` variable as a mapped type of functions taking `ConfigArgs[K]` and returning `ConfigRet[K]` for each key `K`.  The compiler lets us assign `config` to this variable, because it's able to expand that mapped type into the same specific type as `config`.

And now the `getConfig()` function is seen is performing an operation on `_config[path]`, a value of type `(...args: ConfigArgs[K]) => ConfigRet[K]`, and therefore it accepts a rest argument of type `ConfigArgs[K]` and produces an output of type `ConfigRet[K]`.

So everything still works from the caller's side, and the implementation is also type checked.

Note that there is conceptually no difference between `typeof config` and `typeof _config`, but the compiler sees `typeof _config` as representing the generic relationship between input and output in a way it cannot see for `typeof config`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBADgQygCxgXhgbwFAxgQQC4YByZEAWwFMSAaXGAIWJIgFc44QAnKOhgMItQYKAmB9sAXxgIIMEdGzYoATzhUm6GGzABrMCADuYZYtjMtGTFIDcZ8NAXgAZgEsA5tpx4A2ohQAOnwAXWIACgBKdAA+GDA2ABtE+j8A5EDGMJgo4kZYpnoGfyQMgWzwnzxZCTcANypUmCliKrxxKHqqYgAjEBBEqgRTPClotDjGehk5Z0goZTUNGAFXT20lqhAXOfcPe2wAEypgRIRuTRddWvAYDyooVbA9gA0AHgBpGCoADygqMCHeR6KiqbYrNYeGLhBjpYgfJqBJHnDwQYgABXOCGo-24EDeTz2vg+IRi2EixAASg82NwwAAVdRUAmQ4mkg5XMA3MB3B6EzwAJk+3z+AKBMBBYJ2-KhMLwcJgCIYSMCKLRMEx3GxDyoeJZz08bLJFJg1KgtIZTP1RJJcSqF3NdN2hvSIXCKrVkVsMAA9D7vtxuDwAIQwBh+mAAWmjMdjcbiAD8k8mEwQYBA4BcEIdZNwPGxqKIYBQ2E5kAgGrIYOa4INq0zw-6U82W62UzA3tGdPpDCYYG55IZYHIIJ4wAgenWoCB6xoVdJlJzubzHpCAMzC37-QHA0HgmXQ2GleGI5F59Wa7W4-Eyo3krAMB0WnIiPayeTDVSREooN0e8-RLMZoWoyGjWoatoLioTIQgaHj4Oe3gwMS-Y8pK+6Qtkl44rqN6srazTQcsMpmkhKFuGhe7SphVI0nSoHMreBFSNg5gwAA+q+nitMhXwURKVGwXsYQMO6Z6osQMoIaibLjHEJEPGy0jaFx+yLtcnS3Pcq5wZuoo7gJUpCZ4h7yseiqnqq56SZC0kQEp0T2nRPKcayrpiVZqLRL6-ogHoCCqLQ6ZUAC77GR4ZpKSxyjKNpMrhOkwTRBGfkBdgcWQglpSZEFmD9ocxAAEQ-CVhXNMl-q6kG3BBb8GgSFQOYAIy5l4PRsLAHggLAArpXymWJQIFUBtVPkjTwtU-PV-w5gKrXyO1nXdTATV9TpexZUEAi5TUnQNMQUDcGwmhjGNqWqGt8WDTtbgFTAxWleVY1VRNWC3cQ0DcBRHgyAO8TLZgHRdL0-SDMMUhAA)